# Squeeze the output of one layer

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to squeeze the output from one layer which has a singleton dimension, but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
p3 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c3)

print(p3.shape.dims)


tf.squeeze(p3)

print(p3.shape.dims)
```

Before and after the squeeze operation, the shape is the same

> [Dimension(None), Dimension(1), Dimension(64), Dimension(64), Dimension(32)]

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify it because you didn't post your code but you probably need to assign the result of squeeze to something then print the shape of that.

If that doesn't help then please update your snippet to include more details like if you're running in eager mode or other things